# Internet connection problems

Tags: internet, modem

I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. My problem is that I cannot connect to the internet with my D-link modem. I've tried using the `lsusb` command. It shows that my modem has been plugged in, but I can not configure the modem to connect to the internet.

Comment: Screenshot of problem and `lsusb` output may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify that it is usb modem or general ethernet modem with wired connection.
You can also try from the network manager 
Go to Dash and type Network .

Answer (score 0):

First, you must fixed IP address of your ubuntu desktop by following step

1. Go to dash, type network connection
2. Select network connection by click on it.
3. In the Wired tab, click Add button.
4. Go to IPV4 Setting change Method to Manual
5. Hit Add button in Address section to fix the IP address then save
6. Connect to new connection by click on network icon on the top bar and select the new connection that you create.

After fix IP address, you can config modem by using browser and type modem IP address in the address bar and follow modem manual for configuration.

Cheers.